# Installation of Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

hai

Can we install visual studio in external harddisk?

pls clarrfy this..

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install it to an external hard drive, but it will only work on the computer you installed it on.

Visual studio cannot be run as a "mobile" application.

Your only option to do this is to setup a virtual machine and install VS on that. You still have to make sure you can run the VM on the computer you connect the drive to.